# Quantify the "volume" of a function space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $L\colon X \to Y$ be a linear operator from a normed space $X$ to a normed space $Y$.

What are sensible ways of characterizing the size of the set
\begin{align*}
\Omega_{\epsilon} := \{u \in X \colon \left\|Lu  \right\| \le \epsilon\}
\end{align*}

If $L$ is a bounded operator, then the number $\epsilon/\left\|L \right\|$ feels like the radius of a unit ball in the space $X$. But this is number feels pessimistic to me, and gives zero for an unbounded operator, which is definitely incorrect.